# Why do I get Error: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to make a Runge-Kutta 4 method and I have to pull an element from my array which consists of 4-dimensional vectors but I recieve the "too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed" error when I try to take the element out.

So my code is as follows. All relevant variables have defined values (I shortened the code for simplicity). The error concernes the "while" loop.

```
def RK4(u,k):
    n=0
    while u[n,1] >= 0.05 or n<=1:      #This is where the error occurs
        w1=F(n*k,u[n,:])
        w2=F(n*k+k/2,u[n,:]+k/2*w1)
        w3=F(n*k+k/2,u[n,:]+k/2*w2)
        w4=F(n*k+k,u[n,:]+k*w3) 
        u =np.append(u, u[n,:] + k/6*(w1+2*w2+2*w3+w4))
        n+=1
    return u

f=np.array([x0,y0,vx,vy])

u = np.array([f])                        
print(u[-1,1])            #Gives me y0
print(u.shape)            #Gives [1,4]

u_fin=RK4(u,k)            #Raises the error
```

My array, u, works outside of the RK4 block but not in it.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is the line `u =np.append(u, u[n,:] + k/6*(w1+2*w2+2*w3+w4))` which is messing your dimensions. You might want to try using `np.r_[u, u[n,:] + k/6*(w1+2*w2+2*w3+w4)]`. Otherwise, please add a print of  `u.shape` at the beginning of the while loop and tell us what you get.

Comment: What don't you understand?  What expression is wrong?  Why it tries a 2d indexing? or why it is 1d instead of an intended 2d?

Comment: `u` enters as (1,4) shape, BUT if you read `np.append` docs, you'll see that it  flattens the inputs.  After one append the shape will (5,), 1d..   Repeated array append in a loop is not a good idea, especially if you ignore the docs, or assume it is just like list append.